# spring code config addResourceLocations on disk

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm saving files to a temp directory located outside of my project and I need to be able to link to them after I save them.

I tried adding a resource Handler

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/photo/**").addResourceLocations("D://photo//");
```

but it doesn't seem like spring understands that the file isn't on the classpath

```
21:58:48.293 [http-nio-8080-exec-14] DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/photo/a.png] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/D://photo//]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@782ce27b]]] and 1 interceptor
```

is there a prefix or something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define absolute path in resources as given below.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/test/**")
    .addResourceLocations("file:///Users/testuser/test/");
```

This example is for *nix, Use proper windows location after file://

Spring resource documentation is provided [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html)

Another personal suggestion: I would try to reduce absolute file dependency as much as possible in any web application. Self contained project will be much more easier in maintenance point of view.

Comment: file: is need by addResourceLocations